# Write xpath for the node containing node value and attribute togetther

Tags: xml, xpath

Suppose this is my XML:

```
<myxml>
   <data key="true">Apple</data>
   <data key="true">banana</data>
   <data1 key="true">banana</data1>
   <data>Apple</data>
</myxml>
```

I need an XPath expression for the tag which contains attribute `key="true"` and node value = `Apple`.

I tried different combinations but not succeeded.

- For attribute I use this `xpath="/myxml/data[@key='true']`
- and for Node value I use this `xpath = "/myxml/data[. ='Apple']/`
- and also try this `xpath = "/myxml/data[.='Apple'][@key='true]/`

but got error.

I have multiple tags in the xpath. `/mappings/mapping[data[@iskey='true'][.='apple'] and data1[@iskey='true'][.='banana']/`

There is a mistake in this path.

How I specify both the attribute and node value together ?

Comment: Expression must evaluate to a node set

Comment: Have you tried `/myxml/data[.='Apple'][@key='true']`?

Comment: Please, be more careful with the quotes

Comment: @Aleh Douhi. You are also write.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the 'and' operator.

From your example:

```
    /myxml/data[.='Apple' and @key='true']
```

Look under http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_operators.asp for more information on xpath operators.

Comment: you have missed `'` after `'true`. I think that was the problem

Comment: oops. The and operator still works, tho.  It makes the predicate more clear, IMHO.